# Shortest Edge Paths node : how do I get the vertex index after the next?

Tags: geometry-nodes

As it says in the title, the Shortest Edge Paths geonode is useful to find the index of the vertex immediately after the starter vertex on the shortest path between this starter vertex and the closest vertex in an array of given end vertices, but what if I want to get the index of the vertex after that? Or more generally, any vertex on the calculated path?

Thank you very much!